# How do I know if a graph exist given num of vertices and degrees? + How can I draw it if it exist?

Tags: graph-theory

A graph with 8 vertices with degrees 7,7,4,3,3,3,2,1

I already know that the graph exist as the sum of degrees is even. But I am quite confused as the first 2 vertices have a degrees of 7.

I found out that it's not possible to have two vertices with 7 degree as it will cause the other vertices to have degrees 2. Is this true and can I conclude that the graph does not exist?

Comment: Hint: handshake lemma.

Comment: Alright, I will try to take a look at it! Thanks

Comment: @SeanRoberson so sorry, thanks to your input, I just realized i posted the question wrongly. I just edited it.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Can you have a vertex with degree 1 if two vertices are connected to every vertex?

Comment: Oh, I just drew it out and yeah it make sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: The outtake here is that Handshake lemma is a *necessary* but not a *sufficient* condition for the graph to exist.

Comment: See https://supremus.sk/math/is_a_degree_sequence_graphic/index_en.php